# Interface segregation in WCF for JSON

Tags: wcf, json, interface, properties

I am a newbie in WCF. I was wondering if we can retrive properties from base interface in the REST output.

Please consider following structure. Product includes IVenueView not Venue. Is it possible to only have Venue.Id in Product JSON response?

```
[DataContract]
public class Product {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IVenueView Venue { get; set; }
}

public interface IVenueView {
        [DataMember]
        Guid? Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Venue : IVenueView
{
        [DataMember]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data** contracts are all about *data* - interfaces define behaviors, so they don't really mix up well. The data contract that you have likely will not work (because the serializer doesn't "know" about the Venue type (it only knows about IVenueView), it won't be able to serialize / deserialize instances of Product.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because serialization and deserialization works with the implementation (actual data) not with interfaces. Moreover for pure serialization you will have to use something like:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Venue))]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IVenueView Venue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The **Venue** property is of type **object** in the client when using _svcutil.exe_.